# Destructuring without "Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined"

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I'm trying to find something about destructuring :

If I do something like this :

```
const { id, category: { categoryId } } = {};
```

It throws an error

```
VM136:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property "categoryId" of "undefined" or "null".
```

because we are trying to access props `categoryId` of category, but category is undefined.

Is there any solution to do this only on one line destructuring ? I tried :

```js
const { id, category: { categoryId = null } = {} } = {};

OR 

const { id, category: { categoryId } = { categoryId = null } = {};
```

But it does not works.
I can easily do that with :

```js
const { id, category } = {};
let categoryId = null;
if (category) ({ categoryId } = category);
```

thanks all !

Comment: `const { id, category: { categoryId } } = {};` is wrong. You can't destructure anything from an empty object. What does the object that you're _actually_ trying to destructure information from look like?

Comment: @Andy I believe the question is how can you avoid throwing an error if some or all of the properties you're trying to destructure don't exist in the object being destructured.

Comment: `const { id, category: { categoryId = null } = {} } = {};` this sentence is correct and works, but you're using here two default value so `categoryId` will endup having `null`, what is the value you want to have in categoryId ?

Comment: I just dont want an error when I try to access categoryId, It can be null or '' or {}, i dont care, this is not my project, this is a simple example to do something more complexe. Just to improve my skills in JS =D

Answer (score 0):

you must have categoryId on right side (in your props)

```
const { id, category: { categoryId } } = {id: 0, category: {categoryId: 0}}
```

**or**

```
const props = {id: 0, category: {categoryId: 0}} // your props have to look like this

const { id, category: { categoryId } } = props;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hav an IIFE that returns the destructed properties and add a check for `category` in it :

```js
const obj = {
  id: 5,
  category: null
};

const {
  id,
  category: { categoryId }
} = (({ id, category }) => ({ id, category: category || {} }))(obj);

console.log(id, categoryId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no syntax to allow you to optionally destructure if something exists, you have to first check that the thing you want to destructure exists.

There's a proposal for [optional chaining](https://v8.dev/features/optional-chaining) and [some discussion around how that might affect destructuring](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/issues/74), but that's not going to help you in the short-term.

In the meantime, you could look at [lodash get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) which prevents the error you're seeing being thrown and also allows you to also provide default values for when something doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with the default value

```js
var { id, category: { categoryId } = {categoryId: 'some'}} = {}

console.log(categoryId)


// When you set a default value for categoryId to it will always get that default value 
// in case the destrucutured value is undefined

var { id, category: { categoryId = null } = {}} = {};

console.log(categoryId)
```

To understand this you can transpile this to ES5 using babel

```
"use strict";

var _ref = {},
  id = _ref.id,
  _ref$category = _ref.category;
  _ref$category = _ref$category === void 0 ? { categoryId: 'some' } : _ref$category;
var categoryId = _ref$category.categoryId;
console.log(categoryId);
```

You can clearly understand from this simplified code how destructuring works under the hood

- check for the value from the object at the right side, if the value is found, ignore default value if there's any
- If the value is not found or it is undefined, check for the default value if there's any else keep it as it is,

In the context of this example, if you see the id and category aren't found on object, so the value of them is `undefined`, but here we have a default value for the category so it uses than value to get value of category, which will be `{ categoryId : 'some' }`. now when you de-structure category further you're actually destructuring `{categoryId: 'some'}`, so final value of `categoryId` will  be `some`

in this example

```
var { id, category: { categoryId = null } = {}} = {};
```

value of category will be `undefined` so when you further proceed to get value of categoryId it checks value of category since it is `undefined` it uses `null`  as default value

Answer (score 0):

If category is undefined the you cannot get categoryId.

```js
const { id, category: { categoryId } } = { category: { categoryId: 1 } };

console.log(categoryId)
```